Researcher status
As part of their postdoctoral life, PhD holders get engaged in more serious research projects, publish in high-ranking journals, attend international conferences, and so on. Would you recommend them to remain independent researchers or to get affiliated with any higher education institution to thrive? Please draw on your own experience to highlight the merits and the demerits of each case.

Better in order to achieve what?

@AdamPřenosil in terms of better access to prestigious journals, grants, tenure, etc.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/120032/life-as-a-financially-independent-academic Duplicate?

There may be a language issue here. Postdocs are not ‘independent’ in the sense of not being associated with an institution. They are paid and have facilities somewhere. However, they should show some independence in what and how they do their work, more than a PhD student and aiming towards demonstrating the independence needed to be a faculty member running their own group. But postdocs are not ‘independent’.

From my experience as a postdoc clinical psychologist, I believe that there are reasons why I would prefer working with higher independent institutions as compared to being independent researcher.
Being an independent researcher can be a rewarding experience but it is also  very challenging. While Independent researcher will enjoy more freedom- in choosing their own research topics, set their own schedule and the ability to change directions without approval from your supervisors, it can often be difficult to identify the most current and accurate resources. Also, the lack of guidance from mentor can also be challenging.
Moreover, you have to figure out a way to secure funding (as grants are usually given to institutions), navigate peer reviews on your own and also find ways to disseminate your research fundings without support from institutional affiliation. The lack of built in network for colleagues also make it harder to get feedback for your work.
Overall being an independent researcher realistically requires high degree of self motivation, discipline and entrepreneurial spirit. The autonomy of pursuing your own intellectual passion without the constraints of universities can still be rewarding for those who choose this pathway.
I find that this page to be really helpful for those starting out their career as a postdoc, and keen to explore your options. I hope that this will help out

I appreciate your insights and the link. It documents the role of research assistants very well!

A faculty position will ease the work and career of almost every researcher. More so in some fields than others.
Independent researchers don't get tenure. They are much less likely to get grants and most grant giving organizations want an institution behind the person to guarantee compliance and proper use of funds.
Independent researchers don't have natural colleagues to gather with daily to discuss research ideas and goals, though some can develop a circle of collaboration over time.
In some fields, independent research is nearly impossible because of the needed equipment and supplies. In other, like math, that isn't the case, but the lack of a coffee room - gathering place - where people bounce ideas around can be a big factor in productivity.
OTOH, independent researchers can submit to journals, both prestigious and others. They can attend conferences, but must absorb the costs themselves and may need membership in sponsoring organizations to do so.
Independent researchers aren't bound by most institutional rules, but, like everyone, must adhere to ethical standards, some of which are easier when you have institutional support, like IRB boards and such.
Even a faculty position at a place that puts low value on research, however, leaves one much like an independent researcher. Places with large research faculty don't have that problem.

I see another perk of being affiliated with a faculty is sometimes you can use ("use" is not a really correct term but whatever) the students of the faculty and their strength on the research. People on master degree often mentor or supervise students of Bachelor degree , PhD often have master degree students

US national lab technical staff are similar to faculty with respect to these perks as well. And various industry labs (although sadly Bell Labs is long gone). And certainly an independent researcher is not eligible for tenure.

At least in my world, grants are only available to people who work at institutions, unless you have a rich friend who just wants to give you money (or you want to scam someone). The institution is responsible for complying with all the associated regulations and pays you a salary rather than grant money going directly to an individual. Anyone who is responsible with their money (like the government) expects this relationship.
An independent researcher is just someone who doesn't have a job as a researcher. That's fine as a hobby. It's not the same as being a professional. Yes there are a couple unusual famous exceptions; I do not think it makes sense to emulate unusual famous exceptions.
